# Is it “en” or “à” + cette occasion-là?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

If we are to translate "on that occasion", would the choice of *en* or *à* dépend on whether we used là at the end or not, i.e. out of the four possiblities

- *En/À cette occasion-là*
- *En/À cette occasion*

Which is more natural or correct to you? Does the choice depend on where you are from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

à is the right one. You can use also 'en' but would sound more pompous, like delivering  a public speech en l'occasion of the Queen's Platinum Jubilee.